# Choose the right digital ocean droplets

Tags: digital-ocean

I am building a nodejs application that will be serving small text files not more than 10 kb. The traffic will max at 300 requests per second and maybe 200.000.000 in a whole month. I cannot decide what is the correct infrastracture for this to work. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use any droplet that has at least 2 cores, which would be sufficient to handle that load with nodejs. Droplets with 1 cpu might run hot at that load

General/Basic/Premium doesn't matter all that much - you can always resize it later

Lmk if you need more help - we can setup some time outside of SO - my API runs on DO as well so I have a lot of experience

Comment: Thank you! If I need any more help I'll ask for it.